# How specific does a noun have to be to have "the"

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Consider these two sentences:

1. *Houses are expensive in that neighbourhood.* 
   ― **All** houses are expensive in that neighbourhood.
2. ***The*** Houses are expensive in that neighbourhood. 
   ― Not *all* houses are expensive in that city, only the ones in that **particular** neighbourhood.

Under appropriate contexts, aren’t both sentences correct?

Comment: These questions are different enough that it's probably better to ask them separately. Otherwise it's tough to write one good answer (and one good title). Please edit out one of the questions and ask it separately, and please give both questions a more specific title.

Comment: There is no real difference between sentences a and b.

Comment: Yeah, these are pretty similar.  Intonation might distinguish them in speech, but the presence or absence of _the_ does not distinguish.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my experience, there is no difference between the two sentences. It would mean only some of the houses if you added an adjective to houses.
ex.

> The **large** houses are expensive in that neighbourhood.

In this case, only the large houses are expensive.

Comment: Large houses are expensive in that neighborhood.  No change in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the article *the* in this particular case makes no difference.  *Houses* is a generic plural noun and therefore can be a [zero article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_article_in_English#Zero_article) construction without changing its meaning.

> Green houses are expensive in that neighborhood.
>   The green houses are expensive in that neighborhood.

No change in meaning.

But, adding the definite article and a secondary characteristic:

> The green houses are the ones that were damaged in the storm.

In this case, we've distinguished that a particular set of houses are different than others.  (i.e. no longer a generic plural.)
The purpose of the [definite article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Definite_article) is to distinguish a particular group of an item.

Compare these two sentences:

> Children know the best things to eat.
>   The children know the best things to eat.

The first sentence uses a generic plural meaning *all* children.

The second is referring to a specific set of children.

A noun becomes a generic plural when it does not refer to a specific set of something.

Comment: I generally agree with this, but is _Green houses are_ the most _expensive in the neihborhood_ different?

Comment: @Mike I left that one out. Green houses remain a generic plural. The definite article is only changing the meaning with regard to the modifier *the most expensive*.

Comment: @Mike I gave a better example sentence.